# ¿Cómo invertir un campo boolean en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito hacer un `UPDATE` con MySQL que invierta el contenido de una columna booleana. O sea, si en el campo un registro tiene el valor `true`, pasarlo a `false` (y viceversa). ¿Cómo podría hacerse eso?

Answer (score 3):

Para registros específicos, por ejemplo con id 123:

```sql
UPDATE `tabla`
   SET `campo` = NOT `campo`
 WHERE `id` = 123;
```

Para toda la tabla:

```sql
UPDATE `tabla`
   SET `campo` = NOT `campo`;
```

Comment: Genio!!! Muchas Gracias. Funciona perfecto

Comment: @Sergio me alegro. Por favor considera **[aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer)** haciendo click en el ✔️, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta (no se te descuenta nada por eso, todo lo contrario se gana reputación).

Answer (score 1):

¿Probaste algo asi?

```
IF campo = true THEN
 UPDATE tabla SET campo = false
ELSEIF campo = false THEN
 UPDATE tabla set campo = true
END IF;
```

Comment: @Awes0meM4n esto no es apto para un comentario. Está bien que se haya publicado como respuesta. Que sea una respuesta acertada, que tenga errores, etc es un tópico diferente.